# Trouble accessing sites with Chromium

Tags: 11.04, firefox, chromium

I'm having trouble accessing www.fafsa.ed.gov with Chromium, I get an "incompatible browser detected" message. I tried using the "User Agent Switcher" extension for Chrome but it did not work, however Firefox 4 and their own "User Agent Switcher" extension did work. I prefer Chromium, but being a student, this is a bit of a "deal breaker" for me. I figured I'd ask before I made the switch to fx4!

Comment: The site works perfectly on Google Chrome, install that and please tell me if you are encountering the same problems.

Comment: I've tried it on both. The initial page comes up fine, but when you try to enter the site is when it has problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run Chromium with a modified user agent string using a command line argument. To pretend you are using Internet Explorer on Windows, run (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then paste):

```
chromium-browser --user-agent="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) ; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
```

This only works if you close all of your Chromium windows first.

Comment: Do I have to run this command each time I want to visit the site, or is the alteration permanent?

Comment: You need to run it each time but you can make that easier by creating a desktop shortcut or editing the menu item.