# What browser header to change to impersonate another OS

Tags: browser

I'm browsing to a site using Ubuntu 20.04 and I get a message like:

```
<browser name> an unknown version for your
operating system is not supported by <this site>
```

I'm using Chrome and I'm using a user-agent extension that switches the user-agent to Chrome on Windows and I'm still getting this error. I'm thinking that there's another header that needs to be changed to impersonate that I'm using Windows? Or what's the trick to have your browser impersonate the operating system as Windows?

[Similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48919/trouble-accessing-sites-with-chromium) which is what I tried above.

Comment: Not a duplicated exactly, but same question: https://askubuntu.com/a/1441886/232606

Answer (score 0):

Your browser sends its user agent to every website you connect to in its HTTP header. This user agent is a “string” – that is, a line of text – identifying the browser and operating system to the web server. The web server can use this information to serve different web pages to different web browsers and different operating systems. For example, a website could send mobile pages to mobile browsers, modern pages to modern browsers, and a “please upgrade your browser” message to Internet Explorer 6 ([according to howtogeek.com](https://www.howtogeek.com/114937/htg-explains-whats-a-browser-user-agent/) & [Use in HTTP - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#Use_in_HTTP)).

If you ever wanted to make your web traffic seem like it was coming from a different browser–say, to trick a site that claims it’s incompatible with yours–you can. All popular browsers offer built-in user agent switchers, so you can change your user agent without installing any extensions ([learn more on howtogeek.com](https://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/)).

Now assuming you're using Google Chrome, you can try some of the extensions  on https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg

Comment: Not what the user asked he wants the browser o say its on windows not Ubuntu. Something i do not think can be done.

Comment: It is exactly what the OP asked. The user agent also contains a string identifying the operating system. You can set that to anything you want.

Comment: What I (OP) am saying is that the usual trick of changing the user-agent isn't working. I am using Chrome. Poking around and researching I see that there are some new headers like `sec-ch-ua-platform` and `sec-ch-ua` and using the Chrome extension ModHeader I can change those as well so that the `sec-ch-ua-platform` is "Windows" etc. however that doesn't appear to be helping.